# Lynx cron job fails on https url

Tags: cron, lynx

I had a cron job with the following command

```
lynx -source http://example.com/daemon.php
```

which worked fine. I than changed my `.htaccess` file to disallow non **https** requests. Now, I get the following error

```
Looking up example.com
Making HTTPS connection to example.com
Retrying connection without TLS.
Looking up example.com
Making HTTPS connection to example.com
Alert!: Unable to make secure connection to remote host.

lynx: Can't access startfile http://example.com/daemon.php
```

I tried changing the url in the command to `https` with no effect. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Update `ca-certificates` package (if it debian based OS) or similar for your system.

Answer (score 1):

use curl instead of lynx -source

LIKE:-

curl http://example.com/daemon.php

Comment: Yes, you may also add `-k` to suppress any https error. So somethng like `curl -k https://xxxxx.com/action.php`

Answer (score 0):

use configuration file (lynx.cfg) for lynx:

```
FORCE_SSL_PROMPT:YES
```

then:

```
lynx -cfg=lynx.cfg https://sslsecuresite.com
```

Comment: I have tested , this method works in most SSL sites (strangely this way does not work in a few SSL sites for my server),  but this answer is also useful.